# XML DML query for attribute

Tags: t-sql, xquery-sql, xml-dml

```
declare @myDoc xml
set @myDoc = '<Form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.mydomain.org/MySchema.xsd" SectionId="ABCD" Description="Some stuff">
<ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">
<Features>
  <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>
  <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>
</Features>
</ProductDescription>
</Form>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xsd, DEFAULT 'http://www.mydomain.org/MySchema.xsd' )
SELECT @myDoc.value('/Form[@SectionId][0]', 'varchar')
```

I need to obtain the attribute value of SectionId as a nvarchar ? how do I do it ?...

T and R
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it even simpler:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.mydomain.org/MySchema.xsd')
SELECT @myDoc.value('(/Form/@SectionId)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS SectionId
```

Since you're never using/referring to any of the `xsi` or `xsd` namespaces, there's no need to declare those.

And since you're only fetching one attribute from one element, there's really no point in using the `.nodes()` function to create an internal "dummy table", either.

Comment: Thanks marc, but I don't add the namespaces in, the producer of the xml does so I have to keep them as the SELECT returns NULL without them. The real xml is actually stored in an untyped xml column not a variable of xml type.

I am using .nodes() since I cannot guarantee that there will be only one. But I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(  'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' as xsd, DEFAULT 'http://www.mydomain.org/MySchema.xsd' )
SELECT Node.value('@SectionId', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS SectionId
FROM @myDoc.nodes('/Form') TempXML (Node);
```